# Problems with implementing a specific code

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

As stated above, I have problems with implementing a specific code on my website.

This is how it should look: https://codepen.io/smalinux/pen/VjXokA.

```
var d1_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d1_li"),
d2_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d2_li"),
d3_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d3_li"),
d4_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d4_li"),
d5_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d5_li"),
d6_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d6_li"),
d7_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d7_li"),
d8_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d8_li"),
d9_li = MorphSVGPlugin.convertToPath("#d9_li");
```

(I don't know how I show the rest of the JS code, but you can see it in the provided link)

Now, I have a Wordpress website and I am not good in HTML/JS/CSS at all. I am using the Avada theme and when I try to implement this, I either get a white box with nothing happening at all when I use the code generator. When I try to implement the codes seperately I see all the animations overlapping eachother and not moving (meaning JS is wrong?).

Now, I hope I explained my problem. If somebody could help me I would be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how are you implementing the css and js? Screenshots would help. Are you using a child theme?